# FORM checking with ajax/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

im trying to send form with ajax and jquery to get result on same page.
I have this code,that im linking from my form action :

```
function check()
{

    var html = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reg.php",
        data: $("#reg").serialize(),
        async: false
        }).responseText;
    if(html == "success") { 


        //Indicate a Successful Captcha
        $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"green bold\">Success! Thanks you may now proceed.</p>");
    } else {
        $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"red bold\">The security code you entered did not match. Please try again.</p>");

    }
}
```

And then i have this rip of my php file :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teemo1 WHERE nick='$nick' and server='$server'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) )
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
$queryy =  

     echo 'fail';
}

 }
```

I need to show in my page with form "Data successfully saved" and if fail "Incorrecta data", but i dont know how to get those echos from php file to my ajax script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
function check(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg.php",
    data: $("#reg").serialize(),
    async: false,
    success:function(html){
        if(html == "success") { 
            $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"green bold\">Success! Thanks you may now proceed.</p>");
        } else {
            $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"red bold\">The security code you entered did not match. Please try again.</p>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `success` function and use the passed value of success function `parameter`, which is `responseText` in your case.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg.php",
    data: $("#reg").serialize(),
    async: false
}).success(function(responseText){        
     if(responseText == "success") {       
      $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"green bold\">Success! Thanks you may now proceed.</p>");
     } else {
         $("#captcha-status").html("<p class=\"red bold\">The security code you entered did not match. Please try again.</p>");

     }
});
```